# Truffle not able to get Solidity Compiler

Tags: solidity, truffle

jaypatel@192 Bridge Contract % truffle compile

## Compiling your contracts...

Error: Failed to fetch the Solidity compiler from the following locations: https://relay.trufflesuite.com/solc/emscripten-wasm32/,https://binaries.soliditylang.org/emscripten-wasm32/,https://relay.trufflesuite.com/solc/emscripten-asmjs/,https://binaries.soliditylang.org/emscripten-asmjs/,https://solc-bin.ethereum.org/bin/,https://ethereum.github.io/solc-bin/bin/. Are you connected to the internet?

I am Compiling the contract using truffle compile but getting this error

Comment: Please, don't use links: past your code instead. Try to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

This error means that Truffle cannot obtain the Solidity compiler from the specified sources. Possible reasons for this error:

You don't have an internet connection. Check that you have a network connection and try again.

The Solidity compiler is not installed. Make sure you have the latest compiler installed